# Using preg_match_all matches within Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm created a regex in PHP by using the `preg_match_all` function to get a SoundCloud audio url within my WordPress post. The regex works correctly without any problem:

```
preg_match_all[0][0] = https://soundcloud.com/anevo-remix/h3llo-anevo-remix-final
```

When I try the `preg_match_all[0][0]` the player doesn't load, but when I put the `https://soundcloud.com/anevo-remix/h3llo-anevo-remix-final` url, the player loads without any problem. How can I use the PHP code such that the player loads?

```
<?php
    $soundcloud_pattern = "/((http:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*|snd\.sc\/.*))|(https:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*)))/i";
    if(preg_match_all($soundcloud_pattern, $subject, $soundcloud_audio_url)) {
    var_dump($soundcloud_audio_url);
    echo ' 
    <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <div id="soundcloud-audio"></div>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        SC.oEmbed("'.$soundcloud_audio_url[0][0].'", {
            element: document.getElementById("soundcloud-audio")
        });
    </script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like (ie use *"View page source"*)?

Comment: Kow i found the problem. when i put the php code cause new line break. but i want remove the new line break in my php code how can i do this?

Comment: *"new line break"* where? How was a line-break causing the problem?

Comment: when i use php code the first double quote ramain at this line `SC.oEmbed("soundcloud url` but the second double quote comes to this line  `"{element: document.getElementById("soundcloud-audio")` i used url manually when i put url between the double quotes in the same line don't cause any problem but when the second double quote comes to new line don't load player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this. I also see no reason to use `preg_match_all`

```
<?php
$soundcloud_pattern = "/((http:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*|snd\.sc\/.*))|(https:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*)))/i";
if (preg_match($soundcloud_pattern, $subject, $soundcloud_audio_url)) : ?>
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="soundcloud-audio"></div>
<script>
SC.oEmbed(<?= json_encode(trim($soundcloud_audio_url[0])) ?>, {
    element: document.getElementById("soundcloud-audio")
});
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```